# Undefined Index: Self-Processing PHP Form with Looped MySQL Data

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a form with the select options generated from looped PHP data. I am trying to pass the selected POST data to the same page for processing. However, something is going wrong. I get an undefined index and print_r($_POST) shows an empty array. Can anyone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Inventory Tables</title>
    </head>
<script src="../_js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../_js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body>

<?php //inventory mysql tables

ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'inventoryconfig.php';
$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

$result = $connection->query("SHOW TABLES");

$table = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
        $table[] = $row[0];
     }

$count = count($table);
$all = "*";
?>

<?php  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
<select method="POST">
    <option value=\"$all\">--Select--</option>\n";
<?php for ($pointer = 0 ; $pointer < $count ; ++$pointer) {
    echo <<<_END
            <pre>
                <option name="$table[$pointer]" value="$table[$pointer]">$table[$pointer]</option>
            </pre>
_END;
    }

global $table;
global $pointer;

?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

<?php } else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$thisTable = $_POST['$table[$pointer]'];

print_r($_POST);
echo $thisTable;
}

$connection->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *undefined index* - which one? Keep going... - Plus this `<?php  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {?>` and you're using `method="post"` which I'm not entirely sure of, or why.

Comment: It's an undefined index for $thisTable (located at the end, there the print_r is). Server request method get sets a default for page load. If request method is GET display the form. Else, do something. Everything works except for when I get to the else.

Comment: Why wouldn't I use post?

Comment: For reference, I borrowed the general structure of the script from chapter 7 of "programming PHP" 3rd edition.

Comment: Firstly `<select method="POST">` - Method doesn't belong in selects, only in `<form>`. As for what you want to pass off as a POST variable, is hard for me to say. Also, `<option>` do not have name attributes but values, only `<select>` is to have a name attribute.

Comment: Thank, you... It was having the name value in the wrong place. I appreciate adding the extra set of eyes. It probably would have been another day before I figured it out.